# Shows Error - failed to extend when a class is extended in SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass

```
.class{
  color:#333;
}

.ex-class{
 @extend .class;
}
```

Shows error:

> ".ex-class" failed to extend ".class"
>   The selector ".class" was not found.
>   This will be an error in future releases of Sass
>   Use "@extend .class !optional" if the extend should be able to fail

---

What makes me in trouble, Sass is compiled fine on all other git Repos on my system, I tried by changing the Sass versions, My team member works fine with this Sass and same version.

Comment: are they one right below the other as in the example? or are they in separate stylesheets?

Comment: Seperate stylesheets and are included, My team member works fine with this

Comment: are you including them in the right order? first the '.class' declaration and then the '@extend'

Comment: Yes all are included in correct order, Also this Sass works fine for my Team members

Comment: Which version are YOU using please?

Comment: I am using `Sass 3.4.6` and My Team mates uses `Sass 3.2.18` and `Sass 3.4.4`

Comment: "My team member works fine with this Sass and same version." => 3.4.6 != 3.2.18 != 3.4.4...

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck in this for some hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@extend` warning were introduced in Sass 3.2.0:

> Any `@extend` that doesn't match any selectors in the document will now print a warning. These warnings will become errors in future versions of Sass. This will help protect against typos and make it clearer why broken styles aren't working.

In Sass `3.3.0`, it stop to warn the user, simply throwing an error:

> Sass will now throw an error when an `@extend` that has no effect is used. The `!optional` flag may be used to avoid this behavior for a single `@extend`.

Please note that `@extend` has been subject to many bug fix in Sass history (`3.1.13`, `3.2.5`, `3.2.6`, `3.2.8` and `3.2.9`), and that particularly when it's used with media queries. I would recommend you and your team to use at least Sass `v3.3.0`.

If your code if written "as it", you shouldn't have any error/warning. If you're using `@import`, or if the block is wholly/partly written inside a media query, there *could* have issues.

Comment: What are the ways for overcome this issue?

Comment: For his particular example, I would have chosen to use a placeholder instead of an `@extend`.

Comment: Is it be possible to get corrected for using `@extend` by downgrading of Sass version?

If so which version should I used?

Is the error is removed by make use of `@extend .class-name !optional` on the Sass?

Thanks for ur support

Comment: You won't have the warning anymore if you're using `!optional`. But, if you're using Sass 3.4, you should not even have it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem:

```
document [name="variable"]" failed to @extend "%variableSCSS".
The selector "%variableSCSS" was not found.
Use "@extend %variableSCSS !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
_styles.scss
```

The problem was solved using @import variableSCSS.scss in _styles.scss

_variableSCSS.scss is the document which contains "%variableSCSS {...}". So check if your @imports are correctly called on the classes you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@import` then check the permissions of the included files  extension. It must be `.scss`